# how many times does 'progressEvents' take place during ajax file uploading?

Tags: javascript

I was new with ajax uploading , i want to add a progress bar during the uploading process.

i add a register function of `progressEvent` , but turns out the function only execute **one time**.so my progress bar will not usefull .

below  is my code ,what 's wrong with my code ? what should i do the right way?thanks!

```js
var fileEle = document.querySelector('#file');
file.onchange = function(e){
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('book',file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onprogress = function(e){
        console.log(e);//this only execute once ,why?
    }
    xhr.open('post','http://127.0.0.1:8080/profile');
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact , the progressEvent will emit for many times.

you should register the `xhr.upload` object

below is the correct code:

```js
var fileEle = document.querySelector('#file');
file.onchange = function(e){
    
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('book',file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){
        console.log(e);//this only execute once ,why?
     }
    xhr.open('post','http://127.0.0.1:8080/profile');
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```